# How to edit a model with one-to-many relations in ASP .NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

**How to pass Objects (another models) when editing a model?**

---

Suppose I have a Company model in my database. It has one-to-many relations with both License and UserProfile tables:

```
 public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection<License> Licenses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting my company from the database the next way (**i'm including both Licenses and Users**):

```
Company currentCompany =
            db.Companies.Include(c=>c.Licenses).Include(c=>c.Users).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == companyId);
```

Right now my Controller Action looks like:

```
public ActionResult EditCompany([Bind(Include = "Id, Name, Country, Role, Licenses, Users")] Company company)
```

And i dont have problems with binding other values (Id, Name etc).

**How should i pass Users and Licenses from View to get them in the Controller Action?**

Comment: Better post the cshtml as well, so we can see if/how those users are mapped to form fields.

Comment: By generating your view code correctly. But are you really editing each  `License` and `UserProfile` in the the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke No, i have CompanyIndex view, where i render partial view "EditCompany" with company details (Name, Country, role) which i can edit, and tables with Licenses and Users. When i edit any Company value (Name e.g) and i dont know how to send Licenses and Users correctly to controller

Comment: If you do not include form controls for each property of each item in the collections, then you cannot send it back again. But if your not editing the data then it would be crazy/pointless to do that. If you want those collections again in the POST method because you need to return the view when `ModelState` is invalid then just get them again from the db.

Comment: @HenkHolterman They are actually not mapped. I don't display them in my EditCompany View, and Html.HiddenFor() method doesn't work in this case, cause it just creates a hidden input, and i cannot pass Object as a value of input. I use @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) for passing Company Id to the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, it's exactly what i am doing right now. I just wanted to be sure, i can't avoid another call to db

Comment: "They are actually not mapped" - so where do you think they would come from?

Comment: You should of course remove the `, Licenses, Users"` part from the binding. And get the data from the Db (or maybe a cache).

Comment: @HenkHolterman Okay so how can i map them if Html.HiddenFor doesnt work in this case

Comment: What do you mean avoid another database call. First you should ALWAYS be using a view model. Second if you have correctly implemented client side validation, you will almost never execute the `return View(company);` code because `ModelState` will not be invalid. Third, using hidden inputs does work, but as I noted you need to create an input for every property of every item in each collection which would be just crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) and [Stepehn Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) we came up to the solution

In my case, as i don't change Licenses and Users while editing Company Details, i should have done this:

1. Remove ", Licenses, Users" part from the binding
2. Get the data from the Db

My controller Action now looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AuthorizeUserRole(Roles = Roles.PortalAdmin)]
    public ActionResult EditCompany([Bind(Include = "Id, Name, Country, Role")] Company company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var getCompanyWithSameName = db.Companies.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == company.Name && p.Id != company.Id);
            if (getCompanyWithSameName == null)
            {
                var getCompany = db.Companies.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == company.Id);
                company.Licenses = getCompany.Licenses;
                company.Users = getCompany.Users;

                db.Set<Company>().AddOrUpdate(company);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("CompanyIndex", "Admin", new{ companyId = company.Id});
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Company with this name already exists: " + company.Name);
            return View(company);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured. Please Try again");
        return View(company);
    }
```

Comment: Just a side note - While you really should be using a view model especially when editing data (and you never need a `[Bind]` attribute when using a view model), in your case its pointless anyway since by default all properties are bound from the request, therefore can be deleted

Comment: And you might want to consider a [RemoteAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx) for client side validation of the Company Name

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes indeed, i don't need to used [Bind] attribute. And many thanks for an advise with RemoteAttribute, found it really useful

Answer (score 0):

you can make array of data which you want to send, then send array to controller using AJAX.
in the example below, the function `SendData` will send `data` to `HomeController`, action `GetData`.

```
function SendData() {
    var url = "/Home/GetData";

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { data: data},
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            //do smth
        },
        error: function () {
            //do smth else
        }
    });
}
```